# How to sort objects inside deep nested array of objects

Tags: node.js, arrays, sorting, nested, lodash

I have a deep nested array of JSON objects as shown below-

```
data = [
    {
        category:{
            category_id:"1",
            sub_category:[
                {
                    sub_cat_id:"1.1",
                    sub_sub_cat:[
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "1.1.1",
                        purchase_date:1676537327563
                        },
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "1.1.2",
                        purchase_date:1677537327578
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    sub_cat_id:"1.2",
                    sub_sub_cat:[
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "1.2.1",
                        purchase_date:1671537327567
                        },
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "1.2.2",
                        purchase_date:1673537327578
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        category:{
            category_id:"2",
            sub_category:[
                {
                    sub_cat_id:"2.1",
                    sub_sub_cat:[
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "2.1.1",
                        purchase_date:167237327567
                        },
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "2.1.2",
                        purchase_date:1675537327578
                        },
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "2.1.3",
                        purchase_date:1674537327578
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    sub_cat_id:"2.2",
                    sub_sub_cat:[
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "2.2.1",
                        purchase_date:1672537327567
                        },
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "2.2.2",
                        purchase_date:1678537327578
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        category:{
            category_id:"3",
            sub_category:[
                {
                    sub_cat_id:"3.1",
                    sub_sub_cat:[
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "3.1.1",
                        purchase_date:1679537327567
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    },
]
```

In the above data (array of objects) inside each object we have category, inside category we have sub_category(array of objects), inside sub_category we have  sub_sub_category(array of objects). Based on the purchase_date inside sub_sub_category array I want to sort 1st level of array of objects(need to sort objects inside data array based on element inside sub_sub_category, no need to sort sub_category's and sub sub category's array. ) in descending order.

If the array of objects is single level I can do it but as my array is 3 levels of array of objects I am unable to sort it. Please help me in sorting the above array.

Expected output:
In data array we have highest purchase_date in last object so it came first and 2nd object has 2nd highest purchase_date and so on.

```
[
    {
        category:{
            category_id:"3",
            sub_category:[
                {
                    sub_cat_id:"3.1",
                    sub_sub_cat:[
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "3.1.1",
                        purchase_date:1679537327567
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        category:{
            category_id:"2",
            sub_category:[
                {
                    sub_cat_id:"2.1",
                    sub_sub_cat:[
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "2.1.1",
                        purchase_date:167237327567
                        },
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "2.1.2",
                        purchase_date:1675537327578
                        },
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "2.1.3",
                        purchase_date:1674537327578
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    sub_cat_id:"2.2",
                    sub_sub_cat:[
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "2.2.1",
                        purchase_date:1672537327567
                        },
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "2.2.2",
                        purchase_date:1678537327578
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },{
        category:{
            category_id:"1",
            sub_category:[
                {
                    sub_cat_id:"1.1",
                    sub_sub_cat:[
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "1.1.1",
                        purchase_date:1676537327563
                        },
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "1.1.2",
                        purchase_date:1677537327578
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    sub_cat_id:"1.2",
                    sub_sub_cat:[
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "1.2.1",
                        purchase_date:1671537327567
                        },
                        {
                        sub_sub_cat_id: "1.2.2",
                        purchase_date:1673537327578
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can project each object to a numeric value that determines its ranking order. In the minimal example below (for clarity), that's the max `arr[i].value`:

```js
let objs = [
 {name: 'fourth', arr: [{value: 5}, {value: 3}]},
 {name: 'third',  arr: [{value: 2}, {value: 8}]},
 {name: 'first',  arr: [{value: 10}]},
 {name: 'second', arr: [{value: 3}, {value: 9}]},
];

let projection = object => Math.max(...object.arr.map(arrItem => arrItem.value));
objs.sort((obj1, obj2) => projection(obj2) - projection(obj1));

console.log(objs);
```

In your example, that'd be the max `category.sub_category[i].sub_sub_cat[j].purchase_date`.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your valuable answer. In my case to map nested array I am doing Math.max(...object.category.sub_category.map(arrItem => arrItem.purchase_date)). But, I am getting o/p in the original form of array of objects(not sorting). Please let me know how to map nested array of objects.

Comment: `sub_sub_cat` is an array, so you can't do `sub_sub_cat.purchase_date`, you'll need `sub_sub_cat[j].purchase_date`.

Comment: Initially I have tried like that but we haven't defined "i" and "j".

Comment: That's what `map` is for.

Comment: Made some modifications to your ex as shown below.
 let objs = [
                                            {name: 'fourth', arr: [{value: 5, value1:[{value2:10}, {value2:12}]}, {value: 3}]},
                                            {name: 'third',  arr: [{value: 2}, {value: 8}]},
                                            {name: 'first',  arr: [{value: 10, value1:[{value2:10}, {value2:12}]}]},
                                            {name: 'second', arr: [{value: 3}, {value: 9}]},
                                           ];

Comment: tried to sort as below-

  let projection = object => Math.max(...object.arr.map((arrItem,j) => arrItem.value1[j].value2));
                                            objs.sort((obj1, obj2) => projection(obj2) - projection(obj1));

Comment: I am getting error-"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')"
could you please let me know where I went wrong, thankyou.

Comment: You're trying to read `object.arr[j].value1[j].value2`, which is out of bounds for the 2nd and 4th objects. You need 2 iterators.